# Matlab automating analysis of graphs using datacursormode

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have to analyse a lot of data, to do this I defined several classifiers of the data. I want to make something dat if I click with the data cursor on a point on the graph it stores the point and subtracts it from the next. So that I can find the peak to peak heigth of a sine. Like y2-y1.

I found the following code to extract the points. Only it's a function that is called every time and has no memory.

```
function out = getIndex(obj,event_obj,X,Y)
pos = event_obj.Position;
d1 = (X-pos(1)).^2 + (Y-pos(2)).^2;
[ignore index] = min(d1);
out = {sprintf('X: %f',pos(1)),...
sprintf('Y: %f',pos(2)),...
sprintf('Index: %d',index)};
% disp(pos(1))
% pos(1)
pos(2)
save pos.mat pos
```

In Matlab you can test with:

```
X = 1:10;
Y = rand(1,10);
plot(X, Y)
```

You can apply the above function to be used with the datacursormode
using:

```
dcm = datacursormode(gcf);
set(dcm, 'UpdateFcn', @(x,y)getIndex(x,y,X,Y))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using another way in here. Instead of setting the callback for data cursor, set the callback directly for the plot.
Extract the (X,Y) by querying the axes 'CurrentPoint'.

> function so2()
>      figure();
>      a = axes();
>      x = -10:0.01:10;
>      sx = sin(x);
>      h = plot(x,sx);
>      set(h,'ButtonDownFcn',{@Click_CallBack a});
>
> end
>
> function Click_CallBack(h,e,a)
>      point = get(a,'CurrentPoint');
>      x = point(1);
>      y = point(4);
>      fprintf(1,'X,Y = %.2f,%.2f\n',x,y);
>   end

Comment: Thanks! (sorry for the many edits, the code formatting does not work somehow...)

Comment: As I couldn't format any code in an response somehow I had to make a new question out of it..
See here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8702342/408041